# Proof that a PGM gives a probability distribution

Tags: probability

A probabilistic graphical model defines a joint probability as:

$$\mathbf{P} (X_1 \in A_1, \ldots, X_k \in A_k) = \prod_{i = 1}^k \mathbf{P}
(X_i \in A_i \mid (X_j \in A_j)_{j \in \text{parents} (i)})$$

Where parents are the parents of node $i$, and there are no cycles in the graph. Now how do I prove the RHS actually defines a probability measure?

Comment: What does this mean:
$\mathbf{P}
(X_i \in A_i \mid (X_j \in A_j)_{j \in \text{parents} (i)})?$ Does this mean a sum over the  parents of $i$?

Comment: @zoli Yes the conditional is over all parents of $i$. So if the parents of 1 is 2, 3, then we have $\mathbf{P}(X_1\in A_1 \mid X_2\in A_2, X_3\in A_3)$.

Comment: That is not a sum. Do you mean 
$$P\left(X_i\in A_i \mid \bigcap_{j\in \text{parents}(i)}\{X_j \in A_j\}\right)?$$

Comment: @zoli Yes that's what I mean.